# How to overcome from overlapping of html elements?

Tags: html, css, z-index

[image]

I am trying practicing to make like above figure. Anyone can help me on this, how to overcome from this type of overlapping , I think that `z-index` will solve this type of problem but I don’t understand how?

But till now I am able to make this figure…

[image]

Here's my code:

```css
 * {
    margin: 0;
    background:#222730;
  }
  .a{
    max-width:100%;
    height:150px;
    margin-top:4.69em;
    background:#4CAAB3;
  }
  .b{
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    margin-top:-12.5em;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;

    background:#222730;
  }
  .c{
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    margin-top:-12.5em;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background:#4CAAB3;
  }
   .d{
    background:white;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    z-index:;
    margin-top:-8em;
    
  }
```

```html
<div class="sq">
<div class="a "></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="c"></div>
<div class="d "></div>
</div>
```

Comment: For a `z-index` to work, the position must not be `static`.

Answer (score 1):

If the dot is `div.d`, than just add `position: relative;` to show it above (and other styles like background, border-radius, etc.).

```css
 * {
    margin: 0;
    background:#222730;
  }
  .a{
    max-width:100%;
    height:150px;
    margin-top:4.69em;
    background:#4CAAB3;
  }
  .b{
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    margin-top:-12.5em;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;

    background:#222730;
  }
  .c{
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    margin-top:-12.5em;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background:#4CAAB3;
  }
   .d{
    background:white;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    z-index:;
    margin-top:-8em;
    position: relative;
    
  }
```

```html
<div class="sq">
<div class="a "></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="c"></div>
<div class="d "></div>
</div>
```

`Z-index` works with only `position != static` (relative, absolute, etc.). Here `position: relative` and default `z-index: auto` is fine because `.d` is the last element in HTML markup (`.a-c` elements has `z-index: auto` too, but they are higher in your markup).

Comment: the default value of z-index is not 1 (and not 0). it's `auto`

Comment: @TemaniAfif: yes, my mistake... It changes nothing on the rest of my post, in OP CSS was no z-indexes specified, all elements have default value (and it doesn't matter if auto or 1). But thanks.